# PHPSESSID inconsistent via JQuery AJAX Post requests

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, ajax, session

I have ReactJS app and I am trying to send AJAX request to get current session information.

Frontend code :

```
  $.post('http://localhost/php/user/getSession.php',null,function(data){
       console.log(data);
    })
```

getSession.php code :

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['Username'];
  if(!isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
    echo "Not set yet";
  }
  $_SESSION['Username']="ASDASD";
?>
```

So on the first request my output should be "Not set yet" and on second one should be "ASDASD".

It works perfectly when I try to access my .php file directly from google chrome and it keeps my PHPSESSID same on every page reload. (http://localhost/php/user/getSession.php)
 https://prnt.sc/szjies

Problem starts when I try to access it via AJAX. It always returns : "Not set yet", and creates new PHPSESSID (deleting any saved values before that) on redirect.
My ReactJS app and php backend are in two different folders, because I use XAMPP for Apache and Mysql (don't know if this could be the issue). https://prnt.sc/szjiwz , https://prnt.sc/szjj52

**How can I make sure that once ReactJS app is created, that my PHPSESSID stays the same(keeping all the values I assign to $_SESSION)?**

Answer (score 0):

As I know, session will be different at server-side every time refresh or close the page (that mean every access to page, new session will be created every time), I don't think it is possible to keep the session through ajax call.

- So I think solution is you should store it as cookies/session at client side instead of storing at server-side, and you maybe store seesion id at client side and send the id everytime with request to remote server if you want to process something with that

Comment: Refreshing the page keeps same PHPSESSID when accessed directly via URL.
The problem is that my AJAX is automatically sending set-cookie property and I don't know how to make it not do that.

Comment: are you sending request in different url? ex: www.localhost/abc.php, www.localhost/qwe.php

Comment: Same file, same location, same apache.

Comment: Sorry but, have you tried to use `setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);` yet ?

Comment: I have , and I believe that I  found out where my problem is.
My main file is index.html. Even tho I am pinging at .php files, I believe that I need to re-create my app to be index.php so that it can process session stuff. Will have to figure that one out yet. Thanks for help :)